# How do I stop Excel 2011 VBA macro on an iMac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2011

I used to be able to type command+period to stop a running macro. Now, nothing seems to stop one. How can I interrupt and stop a running VBA macro, please?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows try  <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>  +  <kbd>**Break**</kbd>

On Mac try  <kbd>**⌘**</kbd>  <kbd>**.**</kbd>